# How to automate object initialization in python3.8+

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

## The Situation

I'm currently working on a small but very expandable project, where i have the following structure:

```
/
|- main.py
|- services
   |- __init__.py
   |- service1.py 
   |- service2.py
   |- ...
```

Every one of these services creates an object and all of them have the exact same arguments and all of them are used in the same way. The difference between them is internally, where they do some, for this question unimportant, thing in a different way.

Now this is around how my code currently handles it like this:

### main.py

```
from services import *

someObject = {} #content doesn't matter, it's always the same
serv_arr = []   # an array to hold all services

serv_arr.append( service1.service1(someObject) ) 
serv_arr.append( service2.service2(someObject) )
...

for service in serv_arr:
    # this function always has the same name and return type in each service
    service.do_something()
```

---

## The Question

My specific question is:
Is there a way to automate the creation of `serv_arr` with a loop, such that, if i add `service100.py` and `service101.py` to the package `services` and i don't have to go back into `main.py` and add it manually, but instead it automatically loads whatever it needs?

Comment: You say you're creating objects, but it appears there's only one object per module - why create an object in the first place? Or do you mean to say the various modules define service types? (in that case, do you expect a list of service types, or a list of instances of those service types?)

Comment: @Grismar Each Module creates one object, that is correct. And yes, Each module defines a service type that has its own way of processing data from an API and filtering out what i don't need/want, which is why i made it so modular, that makes it easier to add more.
What i expect is indeed an instance of each service type, such that whatever needs the data, in this case main.py, can just access each service one by one and get the pre-filtered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, building on this idea:

> [Austin Philp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59959036/12802379)
>
> ```
> # services/__init__.py
>
> from .service1 import service1
> from .service2 import service2
> ...
>
> services = [service1, service2, ...]
>
> __all__ = ['services']
> ```

And the idea of specifically exposed methods and modules from [Factory Pattern](https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/), mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59959036/12802379), i came up with a very hacky solution that works without cluttering global namespace (another thing criticized by @Austin Philp).

## The Solution

I got the idea to implement a method in each module that does nothing but create an instance of said module and each module is mentioned in `services/__init__.py`:

```
#services/__init__.py
from .service1 import service1
from .service2 import service2

__all__=["service1", "service2", ...]
```

```
#services/service1.py
class service1(object):
    def __init__(self, input):
        ...
...
# 
def create_instance(input):
    return service1(input) # create the object and return it.
```

Then in main.py, I simply do this (it is extremely hacky, but it works)

```
#main.py
import services
import sys

# use the __all__ method to get module names. actually
for name in services.__all__:
    service = sys.modules[f'services.{name}'].create_instance( input )
    # do whatever with service
```

This way i can just happily do whatever needed without cluttering the global namespace but still iterating over or even individually calling the modules. The only thing i would have to edit to add/remove a module is another entry in the `__all__` variable inside `services/__init__.py`. It even removed the need to have the `serv_arr` array, because `services.__all__` already has all the names i am interested in and would have the same length as modules used.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @AMC is this a question about why i want to load my modules like this or is it about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really avoid using the `from xxx import *` pattern, as it clutters the global namespace.

You could add a list of available services to `services/__init__.py`

something like this perhaps

```
# services/__init__.py
from .service1 import service1
from .service2 import service2
...

services = [service1, service2, ...]

__all__ = ['services']
```

If that's still too manual for you, you could iterate over the directory and use `importlib` to import the services by their paths.

However, I can't help but think this problem is indicative of a bad design. You might want to consider using something like the [Factory Pattern](https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/) to instantiate the various services, rather than having a large number of separate modules. As it is, if you wanted to make a small change to all of the services, you'll have a lot of tedious work ahead of you to do so.